# how to open modal from component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to display a modal from component .
I have a modal component created with ng-bootstrap like follow (just a body):

`<template id="accept" #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body</p>
    </div>
</template>`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hello-home-modal',
    templateUrl: './hellohome.modal.html'
})

export class HelloHomeModalComponent {
    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

    open(content) {
        this.modal.open(content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
}
```

I really want to be able to open this modal from a component

**See my homeComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    timer() {
        /** want to open this modal from here . **/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

First of all you have to add a `ViewChild` of the template and one change in the `open`-method to your `HelloHomeModalComponent`:

```
export class HelloHomeModalComponent {
    // add reference of the template
    @ViewChild('content') content: any;

    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

    // remove the parameter "content"
    open() {
        // and use the reference from the component itself
        this.modal.open(this.content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
}
```

Furthermore you have to add a reference in your home.component.html:

```
...
<!-- add the #myModal -->
<my-hello-home-modal #myModal></my-hello-home-modal>
...
```

Now we have to add this reference to your `HomeComponent`:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    // add ViewChild
    @ViewChild('myModal') modal: HelloHomeModalComponent;
    constructor() {
    }

    timer() {
        // open the modal
        this.modal.open();
    }
}
```

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 2):

For myself I use the Primeng Dialog module component. You can view it here:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog

It is a really easy to use and looks really nice and I would definitely recommend it.

Comment: can i open modal from  component without button ? btw i shoud like to use ng-bootstrap

Comment: You want toggle visibility based on a boolean value (i.e. variable[true]=show, variable[false]=hide]) so to do it without a button you just have a function that when called changes the show/hide variable to the true.

Comment: Also to open it inside another component you will have to import it into your home component to access the modal.

Comment: i shoud like to use ng-bootstrap But it helped Thank you btw

Answer (score 2):

You can use @angular/material to open modal window:

https://www.ahmedbouchefra.com/angular/angular-9-8-material-modal-example-and-tutorial/

It's easy, and you don't have to use bootstrap:)